# Fill UIView background color with percentage changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uicolor

I have UIView.

My JSON object every time return percentage count like 45% or 68% etc..

My query is I want to fill background view color programmatically when i receive success json result.

Suppose If i receive 32%. Left to right 35% filling red color remaining 65% white color.

How is possible ?

Can you give me sample code ?

Comment: use progress bar. That will achieve

Comment: In view I need to display some label . Can you give me a sample code?

Comment: instead of filling, y dont you increase the view height with the filled color with animation, so it gives impresison that view is getting filled!!!, You can pace this view in another view?

Comment: @iApps Added an answer. Check if it helps

Comment: @iApps Did it helped?

Answer (score 3):

Take a **UIView** in storyboard and make its subclass as **UIProgressView** or you can make it with code too.

```
UIProgressView * progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
```

You can then use code
Example for **25%** filled red and remaining white

```
progressView.progress = .25;
progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Output

[image]

You can even animate the filling by just changing the progress of progressView in some timer method.
For label just grab a UILabel and add it to the progressView as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a custom `UIView` with `UIBezierPath` like this

```
#define PERCENTAGE      0.3f
#define PROGRESS_COLOR  [UIColor redColor]
#define FILL_COLOR      [UIColor whiteColor]
#define LBL_TEXT        @"Some text goes here..."

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    UIBezierPath *fillPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
    [FILL_COLOR setFill];
    [fillPath fill];

    CGRect progressRect = rect;
    progressRect.size.width = progressRect.size.width * PERCENTAGE;

    UIBezierPath *percentagePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:progressRect];
    [PROGRESS_COLOR setFill];
    [percentagePath fill];

    [LBL_TEXT drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{
                                               NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20],
                                               NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]
                                               }
     ];
}
```

[image]